# Can the sum of the first $p$ factorials ever be a perfect power for $\ p>3\ $?

Tags: linear-algebra, factorial

> Has $$\sum_{j=1}^p j!=q^r$$ , where q,p,r are positive integers, and r > 1 , a solution ?

I solved partially, if r is even, then RHS is a perfect square, and there is no doubt in that. Therefore, the left side must be a perfect square as well.
But for p>3, the last digit of LHS is 3 which is not the last digit of any square. Hence, p<4, and hence manually checking, only solutions are p =1,3.
But i cannot generalize when r is odd. 
Any solution to the next part would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(p)=\sum_{j=1}^pj!$ denote your sum.

Claim:  For $p≥8$ $v_3(S(p))=2$

(Here, as usual, for a prime $q$ and natural number $n$, $v_q(n)$ denotes the order to which $q$ divides $n$.  Thus, $v_3(18)=2$ for example.).

Pf:  One computes that $S(8)=3^2\times 11\times 467$ and from there after you have at least three factors of $3$ in each summand.

It follows immediately that, at least for $p≥8$ your sum could not be any power of degree greater than $2$.  As you have already addressed the case of squares, we are done (after a simple search for small $p$).

Comment: You answered despite of the demanding style ?

Comment: @Peter  I didn't look at the comments, you are right about the tone.

Comment: @lulu I think users should not be encouraged to get answers this way. So, my suggestion is to delete the answer , although it is a very nice answer.

Comment: @Peter I'm on the fence.  The question itself is very well posed, I thought.  The OP addresses a major subcase of the problem.  The tone of the comments is bad, and had I read them I would have stopped thinking about the problem.  As it is, I think the question is mathematically interesting so I'm going to leave the solution up, though I do think you have a point.

Comment: @lulu I think you are right, and the elegant solution is surely useful also for other users.