# Prove that $1 !+2 !+\cdots+n !$ cannot be a perfect power

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $n$ be an integer greater than three. Prove that $1 !+2 !+\cdots+n !$ cannot be a perfect power.

**Proof**:

For $n=4,$ we have $1 !+2 !+3 !+4 !=33,$ which is not a perfect power. For $k \geq 5, k ! \equiv 0(\bmod 10) .$

It follows that for $n \geq 5$
$
1 !+2 !+3 !+4 !+\cdots+n ! \equiv 3 \quad(\bmod 10)
$
so it cannot be a perfect square, or an even power, for this reason.

For odd powers, the following argument settles all cases:

one checks the claim for $n<9$ directly; for $k \geq 9, k !$ is a multiple of $27,$ while $1 !+2 !+$ $\cdots+8 !$ is a multiple of $9,$ but not $27 .$

**Hence $1 !+2 !+\cdots+n !$ cannot be a cube or higher power**.

But if $1 !+2 !+$ $\cdots+8 !$ is a multiple of $9,$ but not $27 .$ then WHY it cannot be cube or higher power ???

This is confusing me for an hour , i am missing something , can someone pls tell me what is it?

thankyou

Comment: Think about prime factorization. A cube of a number should have prime factors with powers that are multiples of three.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the sum of the first $p$ factorials ever be a perfect power for $\ p&gt;3\ $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079389/can-the-sum-of-the-first-p-factorials-ever-be-a-perfect-power-for-p3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n^k$ is a multiple of a prime $p$, then $n$ must be a multiple of $p$ and hence $n^k$ a multiple of $p^k$. In particular, a cube or higher power is either a multiple of $27$ or not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: thankyou very much,it helped me a lot...